# How to force containers to reorganize on disappearance of others in Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a Vue project in which I'm displaying information about all projects hosted on a GitLab instance, e.g. name, ID, ... and most importantly, associated pipelines and their schedules.

I know how to display all projects (1 project = 1 card) and change their CSS behavior depending on their properties. For instance, the grey cards below correspond to projects with no scheduled pipelines and the blue ones have some pipelines scheduled:

[image: Example of displaying all projects with different colors regarding their properties' status]

Now I'd like to offer an alternative option to the user by letting them clicking a checkbox for displaying the projects with scheduled pipelines only.

On the page displaying the cards, I added the checkbox:

```
<template>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="showOnlyScheduled"
    value="false"
    id="checkbox-style"
    v-model="checked"
  >
  Show only projects that have scheduled pipelines

  <div class="row">
    <div
      class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
      id="card-grid"
      v-for="project in projects"
      :key="project.id"
    >
      <Schedules
        :projectName="project.name"
        :projectId="project.id"
        :projectUrl="project.web_url"
        :checkBoxChecked="checked"
      ></Schedules>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in the file handling card displaying:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      class="card card-block"
      id="card-style"
      :class="{ 'has-no-pipelines': !hasPipelines(), 'has-pipelines': hasPipelines(), 'disable-card': !hasPipelines() && checkBoxChecked}"
    >
      <div class="card-block">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <a
            id="title-link"
            :href="projectUrl"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >{{ projectName }}</a>
        </h5>
        <div class="card-text">
          <div v-if="this.schedules.pipelines.length > 0">
            <div v-for="(pipeline,index) in schedules.pipelines" :key="index" id="schedules">
              <p>
                <a
                  :href="projectUrl + '/pipeline_schedules'"
                  id="link-schedules"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >Pipeline #{{ pipeline.id }}</a>
                - {{ pipeline.description }}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-else id="no-schedules">
            <div>
              <div>No scheduled pipelines yet.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Schedules",
    props: {
      projectName: String,
      projectId: Number,
      projectUrl: String,
      checkBoxChecked: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      schedules: {}
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.GitLabAPI.get(
      "/projects/" + this.projectId + "/pipeline_schedules",
      {},
      [this.schedules, "pipelines"]
    );
  },
  methods: {
    hasPipelines() {
      if (this.schedules.pipelines.length > 0) return true;
      else return false;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  .has-pipelines {
    background-color: #1565c0 !important; /* blue */
  }

  .has-no-pipelines {
    background-color: #424242 !important; /* grey */
  }

  .disable-card {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

This code indeed makes the cards with no scheduled pipelines disappear ... but the cards do not reorganize so to be next to one another:

[image: Cards displaying after hiding those with no pipelines]

I guess the cards don't realign because even though I disable some CSS properties, it doesn't make the containers disappear from the DOM.

How can I make the cards realign after I made some of them disappear?

Comment: Ok, so each card is responsible for getting its own data via an api call? That makes things trickier, (and probably quite slow). How does the parent component (that creates the list of cards) work - does it just have an array of ids that it iterates?

Comment: @Steve indeed, it iterates over the project IDs with a `v-for` directive.

Comment: Ok so the issue is as you mentioned - although the cards are hidden, the columns they are wrapped in are not. There are a few ways you could fix it. I think the cleanest way would be to have the parent element contain all the data in the projects list, not just the ids. Then you can simple filter this list as required, removing cards from the dom instead of hiding them

Comment: Another option would be to have the v-for directly on the `Schedules` component, rather than a wrapping div. You would need to add the bootstrap col classes, and the disable-card class to the top level element in the `Schedule` component

Comment: a middle way would be to emit an event after the ajax calls in the child components, that the parent can listen to and update a display property on the current project. I created a pen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/sf-steve/pen/NJxMgd